# PfSense: redirection to authentication / login page from HTTPS links for unauthentified users

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, redirect, pfsense, dns-zone

I've installed and configured pfsense 2.2.4

it works well and redirects unauthenticated users to the login page, as long as they use http; but when I type an https link the redirection doesnt work.

After lots of search I found that enabling https solves the issue but now i have an issue of certificates and users will always have that warning saying the web page is not secure. Which is unpleasant.

I found lately lets encrypt that gives free certificates. but This requires me to buy a domain name and for that i might need a public IP.( if i understand well)

All i need is that when a user is not authenticated, and type https://google.com it redirects it to the login page.

why i need this is because most modern browser will add https automatically without your permission.